# Sizing of high voltage electric vehicle cables

Tags: high-voltage, cables

I would like to know how to find the wire cross sectional area (mm^2) for high voltage cables for electric vehicles.

I also would like to know how to choose the number of strands.

System voltage is around 800V. So, I am thinking my cable should be chosen for 1000VDC.

Comment: Votlage doesn't have any impact on cable size. Votlage dictates insulation type and size. Current has an impact on cable thickness, but you haven't given us current, allowed temperature rise, allowed votlage drop or lenght of cable.

Comment: The cost is often a deciding factor, if there is a cable that will do the job and it is cheap because it is common then that will be used instead of having a cable made...

Comment: @Puffafish Hey thanks for your inputs. I am not actually looking for the answer. I am looking for the method of finding the sq mm used for given load current, operating temperature, length and votlage drop.. Could you please point me to some source or describe what you know as an answer?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I would not worry about the cost, since I do need significant protection and insulation in my system.

Comment: Load current and voltage drop give you the minimum desired resistance (Ohms Law). The required length then gives you a figure for resistance per metre (or kilometre), so find a cable with that value or less.

Comment: @Finbarr Okay thanks for this

Answer (score 5):

The 'size' of a wire in mm<sup>2</sup> refers to the area of the copper conductor only, which is determined by the current, not the voltage.

Until you get to tens of thousands of volts, where the conductor diameter does matter for surface electric field, the size of the copper conductor is unrelated to the voltage.

For voltages below a few thousand volts, it's the thickness and type of insulation that determines the voltage rating.

Although the system voltage is nominally 800 V, you can expect transients well above that in normal use, and then yet bigger ones in abnormal use. I would be very surprised if the regulations around electric vehicles allowed a rating as low as 1000 V for wiring an 800 V system.

The required insulation thickness and type will be driven as much by its physical strength as by its electrical strength. You don't want the insulation round a cable to be damaged or punctured during installation, destroying its insulation properties.

There is no simple single formula for the area of copper wire as a function of current, as it's the softening temperature of the insulation that determines how much heat the wire can produce, and therefore what current it can carry. A single wire in free air in a cool ambient with high temperature insulation like PTFE or fibre-glass can be rated to carry a far higher current than bunched PVC insulated wires in a conduit in a high ambient.

With all those caveats, 10 A/mm<sup>2</sup> will get you into the right sort of ballpark for wires up to 10 A or so. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) gives a table of ampacity versus wire gauge for various ambient temperatures. However check what assumptions it makes, automobiles can have a very high ambient, and I would not be surprised if the high operating voltage needs a lower assumed temperature rise for the insulation than a for a building.

When the voltage gets very low, say 12 V for a distance of a few metres, then the voltage drop from end to end may become the limiting factor, and require an increase in the copper area above that needed for heat. This will not be a problem at 800 V until you get to hundreds of metres.

Comment: Those were some valuable inputs. Could you also point me to a source where I can understand how to find the cross sectional area depending on my load current?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I do understand things better now. Clearly, there is much engineering work to be done considering the amapacity, ambient temperature, insulation, etc.